# query returns the same value multiple times

Tags: mysql, query

I have following command :

```
select * 
from Books  
JOIN Keys ON Books.Bnumber = Keys.Bnumber 
where ( 
    Books.Author1 like '%,%' and 
    Books.Author1 like '%,John%' or (
        Books.Author2 like '%,John%' and 
        Books.Author2 like '%,%'
    )
) and 
    Name1 like '%' and 
    Keys.Keyword like '%' 
order by NAME1 ;
```

**The query returns the same record multiple times.**

The repeating parts in query (`Books.Author1 like '%'`...) are needed, for my application requires it. ( I think it should have nothing to do with my problem)

What could cause this?

Comment: Yes, the table **Keys** contains multiple equal values of **Bnumber**, but that is required because 1 Book has multiple keywords. So is there any way to prevent it anyway? In addition the query uses **Keys.Keyword** not **Keys.Bnumber**

Comment: `like '%,John%'` is a subset of `like '%,%'`, so why have both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The query returns the same record multiple times.

Variants:

1. one of source tables (or even both) contains duplicates;
2. the records are NOT duplicates, there exists at least one field (in a record pair which seems to be duplicates for you) where values differs.

> the table Keys contains multiple equal values of Bnumber, but that is required because 1 Book has multiple keywords.

It is variant 2.

You make a mistake while thinking that the records are duplicates. They differs - at least in `Keyword` field taken from `Keys` table.

You may "compress" the output obtaining one book per recodset by grouping and concatenating all keys into one field with keys list separated by comma:

```sql
SELECT Books.id, 
       Books.Bnumber, 
    /* another fields from Books table */
       GROUP_CONCAT(Keys.Keyword) Keys_list
FROM Books  
JOIN Keys ON Books.Bnumber = Keys.Bnumber
/* all WHERE conditions which you need */
GROUP BY Books.id, 
         Books.Bnumber, 
      /* another fields from Books table */
```